# Rails routing, NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3.2 and Ruby 4. When I browse to http://localhost:3000/account/new I get an error:

```
NoMethodError in Accounts#new
Showing D:/row/dev/basic/app/views/accounts/_form_account.html.erb where line #1 raised:
undefined method `accounts_path' for #<#<Class:0x42c8040>:0x6daa960>
Extracted source (around line #1):
1: <%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>
2: 
3:   <div>
4:    <%= f.label :username %><br>
```

I created Account views using `rails generate controller Controllernames index show new edit delete`. I also ran `rails generate model account`.
According to the online Rails course I'm following this should create in routes.rb:

Edit: I used `rails generate model accounts`, so with the s at the end.

```
  resources :accounts
  get 'accounts/:id/delete' => 'accounts#delete', :as => :accounts_delete
```

However, this was not created in routes.rb. My routes.rb after some editing is:

```
Basismysql::Application.routes.draw do

  # Public pages
  get '/page1' => 'pages#page1'
  get '/page2' => 'pages#page2'
  get '/page3' => 'pages#page3'

  get "/account/index" => 'accounts#index'
  get "/account/show" => 'accounts#show'
  get "/account/new" => 'accounts#new'
  get "/account/edit" => 'accounts#edit'
  get "/account/delete" => 'accounts#delete'
  get 'account/:id/delete' => 'accounts#delete', :as => :accounts_delete

  devise_for :users
  root :to => 'pages#index'
end
```

New.html.erb is:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Accounts#new</h1>
  <p>Find me in app/views/accounts/new.html.erb</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <%= render "form_account" %>
</div>
```

And _form_account.html.erb is:

```
<%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>

  <div>
   <%= f.label :username %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>
  <div>
   <%= f.label :firstname %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
  </div>
  <div>
   <%= f.label :lastname %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :organisation %>
    <%= f.text_field :organisation %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Part of the account controller is:

```
  def new
    @account = Account.new
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    if @account.save
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      render('new')
    end
  end

private
    def account_params
    params.require(:account).permit(:username, :firstname, :lastname, :organisation)
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In addition to:

```
resources :accounts
```

you probably need:

```
resource :account
```

You've started it by adding the routes piece-meal to the routes file, but some of those need to be `PUT`s or `POST`s or `DELETE`s. `resource :account` is a simpler shortcut to do it (correctly).

Comment: Thanks ```resources :accounts``` worked. I assume you mentioned ```resource :account``` because I wrote ```rails generate model account```. This was actually a type in my question, I did indeed use ```rails generate model accounts```

Comment: @Nick you should use singular `account` in model creation and corresponding routes for this `account` model would be `resources :accounts`. You don't need `resource :account` at all here.

Answer (score 1):

```
get "/account/index" => 'accounts#index'
get "/account/show" => 'accounts#show'
get "/account/new" => 'accounts#new'
get "/account/edit" => 'accounts#edit'
get "/account/delete" => 'accounts#delete'
get 'account/:id/delete' => 'accounts#delete', :as => :accounts_delete
```

This isn't the way you should create routes, they are all unnamed(besides the last one), non-restful and all are `get`, replace this with

```
resources :accounts
```

And your error will gone

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
rails generate controller accounts index show new edit destroy
```

Note: you must use **accounts** and not account while generating the controller

```
rails generate model account
```

Note: you must have account as singular

in routes.rb

```
map.resources :accounts /or
resources :accounts
```

depending upon the version of rails

Comment: Thanks, rails generate model account was a typo. I indeed used rails generate model accounts